# Map Works When Debugging Android App, But Not When Downloaded from Market

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-play

I have published an Android app to the Android Market. When I test the app on my device, installing it from Eclipse, the Google Map that is contained in the app loads as expected. However, when I download the version of the app from the Android Market, the map tiles do not load.

Any ideas about why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Google Map API key for Release keystore and signed the application with Release key .